# How to cycle with dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I would need to color the days of a months using a datepicker with the following logic: starting from a date in database, i would like to color in orange next 8 days, then next 2 days in green and so on for every following month.

I have the following code but i need a loop:

```
private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  
{
    if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
    {                
        DataTable asistencia = OperadoresForaneosAsistencia((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];                  

        if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
            string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();
            Tipo = asistencia.Rows[0]["TipoJornada"].ToString();

            if (Tipo == "1") //Tipos de Jornadas
            {
                DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);                      
                DateTime fechatemp = DateTime.Today;                        
                DateTime primero = new DateTime(fechatemp.Year, fechatemp.Month, 1);
                DateTime ultimo = new DateTime(fechatemp.Year, fechatemp.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1);                      

                int counter = 1;
                for (DateTime n = FechaJornada; n <= ultimo; n=n.AddDays(1))
                {
                    int rem = counter % 10;

                    if (rem >= 1 && rem <= 8)
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
                    }

                    counter++;
                }                        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[calendar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/872jh.png)

Comment: Please write your questions in English.

Comment: An apology since I was in Spanish the title, I'm still learning English.
How to cycle with dates?

Comment: do you want to customize an existing datepicker? or write your own? any existing code to share?

Comment: Thank you, at the moment I have it as follows, but with only one achievement paint from a date that comes from the database until the days that I increase it.

Comment: How can I put the code I have, since it indicates that I exceed in characters

Comment: I have modified my question and I have placed the code I have at the moment @dlatikay

Comment: I edited your question but i think you have to edit more. I can't understand the question. Please transalte Descanso/Fecha

Comment: Are you working only on a month? Or on all the year? Is the cycle 8+2 always starting from database date? I think you need write code on DayRender and not in general. In this way you can Always calculate module between database date and your date

Comment: Thank you @Emanuele
It would be for the whole year and the cycle should start the date of the database until the end of the year.

Comment: Can you add aspx code and more code behind? Which datepicker are you using? MAybe it's a calendar, not a datepicker. Try to read the following: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4t1kwcd.aspx

Comment: I tell you that I can paint the days with the code that is in the question, they paint without problems, only that I have to add manually so to speak. What I want to do is to convert this condition into some cycle so that it takes the date of the day until the last date of the month and the automatism in the 8 days of green and the 2 days of orange.

I just do not know how to run

Comment: I'm trying something like this but I do not get it                                  DateTime FechaJornada = Convert.ToDateTime(iRow["Jornada_Ini"]);
DateTime fechatemp = DateTime.Today;
DateTime primero = new DateTime(fechatemp.Year, fechatemp.Month, 1);
DateTime ultimo = new DateTime(fechatemp.Year, fechatemp.Month + 1, 1).AddDays(-1);
DateTime n;
for ( n = FechaJornada; n <= ultimo; n = n.AddDays(1))                        
{                            
TextBox1.Text = ultimo.ToString();
e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
} @Emanuele

Comment: I can read the previous code from the first post. We are trying to help you. Can you answer the question? They are important to answer. If you are using the calendar you have the event daterender and you don't need loop. Can you edit your post adding aspx code and the event in which you are working?

Comment: What is e in e.Cell.BackColor? It derives from an event

Comment: Thanks, before me if I have the following:                                      private void calFecha_DayRender(object source, DayRenderEventArgs e)  
{ bool final = true;
 if (ddloperadores.SelectedValue != "Todos")
{
DataTable asistencia = OperadoresForaneosAsistencia ((int)WAPS.Globals.ConvertTo(txtNumOperador.Text, 0)).Tables[0];            
if (asistencia.Rows.Count > 0)
{ DataRow iRow = asistencia.Rows[0];
string Tipo = iRow["TipoJornada"].ToString();
Tipo = asistencia.Rows[0]["TipoJornada"].ToString();

Comment: Edit Always your first post.

Comment: You see how I have formatted your question with the whitespace? Please do that in the future. Following standard C# conventions increases readability of your code and makes you more likely to receive a useful answer.

Comment: Thanks @mason will take it into account.

Comment: Remove `DateTime fechatemp = DateTime.Today;                        
DateTime primero = new DateTime(fechatemp.Year, fechatemp.Month, 1);`
if not needed.
Remove also `Tipo = asistencia.Rows[0]["TipoJornada"].ToString();`

Comment: Remove them from the code as they were not useful. @Emanuele

Comment: The type of Journey if it is necessary since I have several this is the first one that should show me 8 in green and 2 in orange there is another type of Journey that should show me 12 days in green and 3 in orange until the eighth working day. But for now I just want to see how to do the first to be able to perform the others. @Emanuele

Comment: You already have, the code was duplicate. And, in general, avoid to do queries in dayrender event.

Comment: If it was what I was seeing, I already removed it @Emanuele

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference of your comment do the following in the loop:

```
int counter = 1;
for(n = FechaJornada; n <= ultimo; n.AddDay(1))
{
   int rem = counter % 10;
   if (rem >= 1 && rem <= 8)
       e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
   else
       e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;

   counter++;
}
```

**EDIT**: after moving in dayrender

```
   // compute FechaJornada then...
   if(FechaJornada < e.Day.Date)
   {
      int rem = (e.Day.Date - FechaJornada).Days % 10;
      if (rem >= 1 && rem <= 8)
          e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkGreen;
      else
          e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkOrange;
   }
   else
      e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
```

Comment: I try to run a test with the code but it tells me that it can not be applied to operators of type 'System.TimeSpan' and 'int' @Emanuele

Comment: Ah sorry because you are using DateTime in loop. I'm going to edit my previous post.

Comment: Thanks @Emanuele , this marks me the whole green calendar does not mark the days of rest, and so in the following months

Comment: @Molitaa i have tested the code in a console application and it works. Moreover i have given you the solution: % 10 . Can you please post all the code, be more complete and try to be more precise?

Comment: Thanks, I have modified the code as I have it and attach an image so you can see how it appears to me, thank you very much for continuing to give me your support.

Comment: @Molitaa Ok, now it's clearer. You can keep only the code i wrote in my post (i edited it again) in dayrender event. You can move the code you added before my code in first post in OnLoad or Page_Load event.

Comment: Well make the changes to do the test, before the date can be left blank (without any color) @Emanuele

Comment: So before `e.Day.Date - FechaJornada` test if you are before e.Day.Date @Molitaa - I edited my post again (now it's not verified)

Comment: I already do a test if you are marking the 8 in green and the 2 in orange but I do not take the Release date to start the initiation on the 10th begins to paint from the 11th and I should start a painting on the 10th @Emanuele

Comment: I see that I also appear in white before the FechaJornada, but I see that it starts to paint a day after the FechaJornada how can I start it from the FechaJornada
@Emanuele

Comment: Done, modify if (GivenDate <= e.Day.Date) and start if (rem> = 0 && rem <= 7)
To start from the DateJornada, many thanks @Emanuele

Comment: Thank you very much @Emanuele you helped me too, and I hope not to get out of control since I am still in the process of learning, that you have a very nice Tuesday. I have marked your answer with a popcorn if there is any other way to mark it as useful for me to do so. regards